# Is there a quick way to get or buy cards for a specific recipe?

Tags: hearthstone

I recently started playing Hearthstone and I've got to the point where I've leveled every class to 10 or more, and so I have all the cards for each of the "Core" decks.

The game shows 2 more deck recipes for each class though, and I would like to try them, but it shows that I have anywhere between 0-20 cards for any of them, so there is a lot missing.

My question now is how can I quickly get those cards to be able to build and play with the other deck recipes? The game doesn't explain this well.

I don't mind paying real money if that is the "fast" way to get the cards, but even that isn't made clear as an option in the game.

I want to avoid spending 100's hours grind-playing just to gain cards though. I'd rather pay directly and have more fun with my playtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deck recipes are popular premade decks that have a decent success rate in the meta. The recipes (and playstyles of the decks) will change with patches and expansions.

To answer your question, there are 4 primary ways to gain cards:

1. Purchase packs with real money.
2. Purchase packs with in game gold (can be earned naturally through playing and completing quests).
3. Play through adventures/story modes (very few cards that are useful in competitive are gained this way).
4. Crafting cards with dust, used for crafting a targeted card.

Based on your current comments, buying deck packs will be your fastest way of getting cards to fill out the recipes (yes it is random, but it's how they get you). Be aware that different cards come from different expansions, so you many need to buy different packs.

You can disenchant duplicates from the packs to gain dust for crafting the cards you need.